# expand_grid is creating a data frame column, how can I convert them to simple columns

Tags: r, tidyr

```
library(tidyr)
dat <- expand_grid(df = data.frame(x = 1:2, y = c(2, 1)), z = 1:3)
dat
```

yeilds

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
      z  df$x    $y
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     1     2
2     1     2     1
3     2     1     2
4     2     2     1
5     3     1     2
6     3     2     1
```

I would like to remove `df` from the data frame, having 3 simple columns, `z`, `x`, and `y`

I have tried `unnest` but got no where. any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't name the data frame:

```
library(tidyr)

expand_grid(data.frame(x = 1:2, y = c(2, 1)), z = 1:3)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
      x     y     z
  <int> <dbl> <int>
1     1     2     1
2     1     2     2
3     1     2     3
4     2     1     1
5     2     1     2
6     2     1     3
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset is already created, then convert to a regular data.frame with `do.call`, and `rename` the columns that starts with `df`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
do.call(data.frame, dat) %>%
    rename_at(vars(starts_with('df')), ~ str_remove(., 'df\\.'))
#  x y z
#1 1 2 1
#2 1 2 2
#3 1 2 3
#4 2 1 1
#5 2 1 2
#6 2 1 3
```

---

Or another option is to `pull` the column  'df' and then bind with the rest

```
dat %>% 
   pull(df) %>% 
   bind_cols(z = dat %>% 
              pull(z))
#  x y z
#1 1 2 1
#2 1 2 2
#3 1 2 3
#4 2 1 1
#5 2 1 2
#6 2 1 3
```

---

Or using `crossing` in this case

```
crossing(data.frame(x = 1:2, y = c(2, 1)), z = 1:3)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#      x     y     z
#  <int> <dbl> <int>
#1     1     2     1
#2     1     2     2
#3     1     2     3
#4     2     1     1
#5     2     1     2
#6     2     1     3
```

Comment: `crossing()` and `expand_grid()` are not necessarily interchangeable.